# How to use useFormState outside a <Form/>

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-form, react-admin, react-final-form

I upgraded `react-admin` v2.0 to 3.0, i followed this [guide](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/UPGRADE.md).

I have a problem with `react-final-form` and a `jest` test.

I did a custom logic on a button and I need the form values, so I use the `useFormState` from `react-final-form`. It works fine on the application but I have an error while running the `jest` test.

Here is my code in my component

```
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Save } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { useFormState } from 'react-final-form';
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';

const Toolbar = ({ onSubmit, translate }) => {
  const formState = useFormState();

  const handleCustomSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    const data = formState.values;
    onSubmit(data);
  }, [formState.values]);

  return (
    <Button id="SLM_saveButton" onClick={handleCustomSubmit}>
      <Save />
      {translate('ui_update')}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

And here the error

```
useFormState must be used inside of a <Form> component

       6 |
       7 | const Toolbar = ({ onSubmit, translate }) => {
    >  8 |   const formState = useFormState();
         |                     ^
       9 |
      10 |   const handleCustomSubmit = useCallback(() => {
      11 |     const data = formState.values;

      at useForm (node_modules/react-final-form/dist/react-final-form.cjs.js:297:11)
      at useFormState (node_modules/react-final-form/dist/react-final-form.cjs.js:309:14)
      at Component (packages/ui/src/components/Toolbar/component.js:8:21)
      at wrappedComponent.displayName.adapter.displayNameOfNode.type (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:569:33)
      at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:858:32)
      at fn (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:645:55)
      at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js:99:18)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:645:20)
      at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:411:22)
      at Object.shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
```

I don't understand how to use the `<Form/>` and the `useFormState` correctly in `react-admin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a `<Form>` around your `<Toolbar/>` in your test. `useFormState()` looks in the React context for the containing form. Apparently in your application, your `<Toolbar/>` is always inside a `<Form/>`, so you need to replicate that for the test.